# Hide empty folders and other files in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse CDT, how can the navigator and project view be filtered to hide empty folders and other undesirable file types?

The customize options seem to be a bit limited e.g. hide non-c content also hides makefiles which isn't helpful to me.

Is there a plug-in to add this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

In the project explorer panel, click on the down arrow icon in the top left > customize view > flag 'Empty folders'.